# Google Sheets Arrayformula with some sort of concatenate/textjoin/something similar for all rows

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I'm trying to do an arrayformula that goes down all rows. I want it to grab the text from *a specific row* if the row that it's on meets conditions.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: have a formula in G5 that iterates through A:F. If the cell = "N", the grab the text from *row 4* and concatenate it into a single string, with the text separated by commas.

[image]

I've looked at other questions on stack overflow but they're not quite the same.

Here's a sample [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9f_p2drG9YmTbxGS-PbXA7clU7KVZUImCaWun916Zw/edit#gid=1698061847)
I've gotten as far as the formulas in K4 and P4, but can't figure out how to make it all one formula.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: solution in a new tab called MK_Help.  I will add to answers if you agree i had the right Idea?

Comment: @MattKing thank you! It works perfectly. Unfortunately I can't mark it as a best answer because you added it as a comment, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A5:F="N", A4:F4&",", )),,9^9))), ",$", ))
```

[image]